# Shortcut to kill a process that's pinned on the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

Is there any extension/shortcut that i can create that allows me to kill a taskbar-pinned application?

The reason i need this is i often missclick the icons and most of the apps take quite a while to load (ex. Visual Studio) and it just forces me to open taskmgr and kill the process there.

Is there any extension that allows me to kill it from the shortcut menu (or whatever it's called this menu)? [image]

I know it's not recommended to abruptly kill a process like this, but in this case, it'd be helpful for me, i don't know if explorer even allows an extension for this, but i can't find any and i'm sure i wouldn't be the only one using it.

Comment: `crtl`+`shift`+`esc` will bring up the taskmgr

Comment: I know, i use that shortcut, but it still forces me to tab to processes and "search" for the process, that is, if i know the name from my head. (i do in this case but)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something like [ShutApp](http://imagia.oprolab.pl/MorePrograms.aspx). I haven't used it so I'm not sure if it works well but according to [Raymond.cc](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/forcefully-close-full-screen-application-or-game-with-superf4/) it brings up a list of running processes that you could terminate on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

[image: ShutApp process terminate list]

<sup>screenshot courtesy of [raymond.cc](http://raymond.cc)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this! Works awesome, it detects the last application "opened" as i press ctrl alt end, unfortunately the caps lock thing is driving me nuts and it's not costumizable at all... i'll see if i can work with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have UAC (User Account Control) enabled and what I usually do is I set the application that's pinned to the taskbar to run as administrator. If I ever click on it accidentally, UAC will make a prompt and I just click on "No"

Comment: That is an inconvenient workaround, very inconvenient...